# Solving large ODE system in Python. How to speed up and optimise memory?

Tags: python, optimization, scipy, generator, odeint

I'm trying to solve a large system of ODEs. My code works, but the problem is that it takes too much time to run. Besides, it consumes a lot of memory. So, could you give recommendations on how to speed up my code and reduce memory consumption?

For example, if you run my conde using n=6, the code doesn't work (at least in my computer 8G RAM) because it requires too much memory.

Also, am I using the generator function correctly? Thanks!

```
# 1. Libraries
import numba
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import pandas as pd
import scipy as sci
from numba import jit
from scipy.integrate import odeint
from matplotlib.ticker import MaxNLocator
    
# 2. The model
@numba.jit
def dxidt(xi, t, ao, aj, d, n, m):
    dx = np.zeros(len(xi))
    past_index = np.repeat(np.arange(0, len(xi)), m)
    for i in np.arange(1, len(dx)):
        dx[i] = ao[i-1] * xi[past_index[i-1]] - (d + np.sum(aj[i])) * xi[i]#aj[i-1]
    return(dx)

    
# 3. Parameters
d = 1.
m = np.ones(1, dtype = int) * [2, 4, 8]
n = 5               # Tree levels: Begins at zero!!!!!!!!!!!!!!


s = np.concatenate([np.arange(0., 0.1, 0.001),
                    np.arange(0.1, 1., 0.01),
                    np.arange(1., 10., 0.1),
                    np.arange(10., 100., 1.),
                    np.arange(100., 1010., 10.)])

# 4. Integration conditions
tf = 10#
steps = 100
t = np.linspace(0, tf, steps)

# 5. ODE
## 5.1 ai constant

## 5.2 ai variable
sol2 = []

def ode_generator(d, m, n, s, t):
    for i in np.arange(0, len(m)):
        xi = np.ones(sum(m[i]**np.arange(0, n)))
        xi[1:] = 1.
        aj = np.ones(sum(m[i]**np.arange(0, n+1)) - m[i]**0)
        tau = np.ones(len(aj)) * np.random.uniform(low = 0., high = 1.,
                                                   size = len(aj))
        tau[0:m[i]] = 1. # Coefficients once!!!!!!!!!!!!!!
        print(m[i])
        for j in np.arange(0, len(s)):
            temp = []
            #       temp_test = []
            aj[m[i]:] = (1 + s[j] * tau[m[i]:])
            ao = aj[0:sum(m[i]**np.arange(0, n)) - m[i]**0]
            ajt = aj.reshape(int(len(aj)/m[i]), m[i])
            init_cond = xi
            print("m =", m[i], "s =", s[j])
            temp = sci.integrate.odeint(dxidt, init_cond, t, args=(ao, ajt, d, n, m[i]))[-1]
            yield temp



## 6.2. Eq. Abundance vs m vs s (ai variable)
eqsol2 = []
for sol in ode_generator(d, m, n, s, t):
    eqsol2.append(sol)
```

Comment: Can you explain your problem more. It looks like it for `n=6`, then you will have about 300,000 equations?  `odeint` is saving 300,000 variables at a few hundred timesteps, so this maybe is saving around 30e6 double precision values, maybe more. This is about 0.3 GB. You are appending the results in a big list `eqsol2`. It would be better to save the results to binary files. Look up `pickle` files, for example.

Comment: Hi. You describe the issue quite well. Yes, for n=6, there are about 300k odes, so this consumes a lot of memory. I am using generators as I guess they avoid storing temporal data (not sure, I'm noob on this), reducing memory consumption, but I'm not sure whether I'm coding it well. I'll check Pickle's library. Thanks!